# Is it a good chord?

Tags: code-golf

## Is it a good chord?

#### Definition of a `chord`:

We define a `chord` as three notes together.

#### Definition of a `note`:

We define a `note` as a number between `1` and `7`, inclusive. As in music, we define `1` as `do`, `2` as `re`, `3` as `fa`, etc. However, the note names are not important. They will not be included in the question and likely not in a golfed solution. `1` is a note. `0` and `8` are not a note. As we will mention later, the input is a list of three notes, and invalid notes will **not appear** as an input. So even if you print the entire Never Gonna Give You Up lyrics when you encounter invalid inputs, I don't care. (However, I don't see how that's more golf-y.)

#### Definition of a `good chord`:

We define a `good chord` as follows:

- If there are any two notes that are the same, disregard one of them.
- Sort the notes.
- Space the result on a piano. For instance, `135` will look like `X X X` and so will `246`, `357`, for instance.
- If any of the notes are adjacent, it is considered a `bad chord` and thus not a `good chord`. That is, a chord containing `1` and `2` is `bad`, so is a chord containing `1` and `7`.
- The only possibilities that are left are:

With three digits,

- 135
- 136
- 137
- 146
- 147
- 157
- 246
- 247
- 257
- 357

And with two digits,

- 13 which could have been 113 or 133
- 14 which could have been 114 or 144
- 15 which could have been 115 or 155
- 16 which could have been 116 or 166
- 24 which could have been 224 or 244
- 25 which could have been 225 or 255
- 26 which could have been 226 or 266
- 27 which could have been 227 or 277
- 35 which could have been 335 or 355
- 36 which could have been 336 or 366
- 37 which could have been 337 or 377
- 46 which could have been 446 or 466
- 47 which could have been 447 or 477
- 57 which could have been 557 or 577

And with one digit,

- 1 which means 111
- 2 which means 222
- 3 which means 333
- 4 which means 444
- 5 which means 555
- 6 which means 666
- 7 which means 777

Note that the above possibilities are already sorted, **while you should not expect your input to be sorted**. Also, the above possibilities are represented as a three digit number, **while your input will be a list of three numbers from `1` to `7` inclusive**.

I would not expect an answer that hard-codes the values above, but if you intend to, or for some reason it is more golf-y, you are **permitted** to do it.

#### Your challenge:

Given an input, decide whether it is `good` or not. Return a true-y or false-y value, a true-y value such as `1` means that it is `good`, while a false-y value such as `0` means that it is `not good`. Do not use ambiguous values like   or `\n` (indicating a newline) or `[[]]` et cetera.

#### Scoring:

This is `code-golf`.

Comment: I see you've had a number of poorly received questions lately. You should try using the Sandbox for feedback before posting your questions (and by "using", I mean leaving them for more than a few hours and posting them after they are voted on).

Comment: Not to be picky, but aren't there 12 notes (in occidental music)? Your challenge doesn't seem to take in account that there is only a half-tone between B and C and between E and F, making your definition a bit weird to me

Comment: I'm not taking that into account because that messes up the input format and makes it harder to explain.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 19 bytes

```
31 D2 AD 0F AB C2 FF CF 75 F8 8D 04 12 85 D0 0F 94 C0 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVLBbqMwED17vmJKFQmKGyUhTaWw6WXPe9nTSikHxzaJK2Iq7GhJEb@@7LiU9ID9Zt6b5/Fg@XiUchiEO2OMv6MY5seqPogKSyi3rK0b1KrlYYFmy6paOQXs4N1XWrTAlJYUGWBv9gMbYJUWgeC4b1Sb0lcA89r5MRmcmNP@A0UFrNEekgiTHORJNFjGxnq0HMP2ICgN98bK6qI0/nBemXp@egFwXngj0fnmIj0Gbymcxi5UiX1W5D1MSbcvcIcddEue8aeeB7DmzwFQPIIVZTYTeB41y1G8nqiMyrORWo2AiMnnVv40gRtFZACbKROcVz30OYRmz8LYOIEOWEmT/ry8oXYXOW13O1xuCKRpAowU7L0hvoyjmXm1EadZZRy/r2mKuUhoYKyHm/LV/hLyZKxGWSu9jQIdzmjDGRyvFKoau0mOs8XqDzlfd3F8sc4crVYY/stDUib7Nk2LJO/x78lUGuNraHDR/syC6c0hnhk8XKmr5LPHlsh@GP7JshJHNzyeN2ta6LHtSK@r/w)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes the length and address of an array of 32-bit integers in EDI and RSI, respectively, and returns a value in AL.

In assembly:

```
.global f
f:  xor edx, edx    # Set EDX to 0.
r:  lodsd           # Load a number from the array into EAX, advancing the pointer.
    bts edx, eax    # Set the bit in that position in EDX to 1.
    dec edi         # Subtract 1 from EDI, counting down from the length.
    jnz r           # Jump back if that is not zero.
    lea eax, [rdx+rdx]  # Set EAX to 2 times EDX -- the bits move up by 1.
    test eax, edx   # Set flags based on the bitwise AND of EAX and EDX.
                    # This checks for adjacent bits being 1.
    setz al         # Set AL based on whether the result was zero.
    ret             # Return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda l:not{*l}&{x+1for x in l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCoMwEEX3fsWsirbZJPEBQr9Es1BKqDBNRLJQxG9PMwxxd@aee2c9wtc7He17jDj95s8E2Dsfzidej3N/Ses32GFxgFckRuKhGKTQojGCoBYdQboZVEraDB13JJfrrHSaa1aKIYn85543GW6VJEGbE/qsTGF6WLfFhdKWWFXxDw)